# How to change values of a pandas DataFrame hierarchical index given a MultiIndex object

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a Pandas DataFrame object with a hierarchical index (i1, i2), and some data column 'x'

```
i1  i2   x
a   0    3
a   1    7
a   2    9
b   0   11
b   1    2
```

Given a pd.MultiIndex object equivalent to

```
[('a', '0'), ('a', '1')]
```

What general approach can be taken to modify the index of the original DataFrame to give:

```
i1  i2   x
c   0    3
c   1    7
a   2    9
b   0   11
b   1    2
```

Note: ['a', 2] does not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of change the index back to columns then put it back to index

```
s=df.index.to_frame()
s.loc[[('a', 0), ('a', 1)],'i1']='c'
df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(s)
df
Out[164]: 
        x
i1 i2    
c  0    3
   1    7
a  2    9
b  0   11
   1    2
```

Comment: Great! As an extension what about if it wasn't required to keep the original values in i2, and instead they reset to incrementing ids?

Comment: @Jinglesting that is more like a new question , would you like show us some example ?